# como ler um Json resultado da google directions API

Tags: c#, http, xamarin, maps, xamarin-forms

Eu estou recebendo esse json do google directions API

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-22.8895625,-47.0714089&destination=-22.892376,-47.027553&key=

eu preciso lê-lo
Mas está difícil.

O que eu tenho até agora: (mesmo tendo consciência que está errado)

```
 public static async Task<List<Model.Localizacao>> GetDirectionsAsync(Localizacao locUser, Localizacao locLoja)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                List<Model.Localizacao> lstLoc = new List<Model.Localizacao>();
                var json = await client.GetStringAsync("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + locUser.latitude + "," + locUser.longitude + "&destination="+ locLoja.latitude+","+locLoja.longitude+"&key=" + GOOGLEMAPSKEY);
                json = json.Substring(json.IndexOf('['));
                json = json.Substring(0, json.LastIndexOf(']') + 1);
                lstLoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.Localizacao>>(json);
                return lstLoc;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

minha classe

```
namespace neoFly_Montana.Model
{
class Localizacao
{
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
}
}
```

Estou usando Newtonsoft e System.Net.Http nesse projeto que é xamarin.forms
Como faço para receber apenas o objeto que contém os pontos que usarei em minha polyline?

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste link google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o HttpWebRequest para conseguir o json da pagina e depois tratar esse json usando Newtonsoft, jogando o json inteiro dentro de um objeto e depois pegando apenas a parte que você vai usar assim:

Codigo do HttpWebRequest para pegar o json:

```
        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        StreamReader sr = null;
        Encoding encoding = null;
        CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();
        string html = string.Empty;

        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-22.8895625,-47.0714089&destination=-22.892376,-47.027553&key=");
        request.CookieContainer = cookie;
        request.Timeout = 30000;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.CharacterSet != null)
        {
            encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);
        }
        else
        {
            encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
        }
        sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding);
        html = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Você também pode adicionar uma proxy nesse request o que é recomendável.

Para transferir o texto do json que esta na variável html para o objeto json você pode usar esse código:

```
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(html);
```

Ele vai utilizar a classe Rootobject que foi criada a partir do json inteiro da pagina do google :

```
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Geocoded_Waypoints[] geocoded_waypoints { get; set; }
        public Route[] routes { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Geocoded_Waypoints
    {
        public string geocoder_status { get; set; }
        public string place_id { get; set; }
        public string[] types { get; set; }
    }

    public class Route
    {
        public Bounds bounds { get; set; }
        public string copyrights { get; set; }
        public Leg[] legs { get; set; }
        public Overview_Polyline overview_polyline { get; set; }
        public string summary { get; set; }
        public object[] warnings { get; set; }
        public object[] waypoint_order { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bounds
    {
        public Northeast northeast { get; set; }
        public Southwest southwest { get; set; }
    }

    public class Northeast
    {
        public float lat { get; set; }
        public float lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Southwest
    {
        public float lat { get; set; }
        public float lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Overview_Polyline
    {
        public string points { get; set; }
    }

    public class Leg
    {
        public Distance distance { get; set; }
        public Duration duration { get; set; }
        public string end_address { get; set; }
        public End_Location end_location { get; set; }
        public string start_address { get; set; }
        public Start_Location start_location { get; set; }
        public Step[] steps { get; set; }
        public object[] traffic_speed_entry { get; set; }
        public object[] via_waypoint { get; set; }
    }

    public class Distance
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Duration
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
    }

    public class End_Location
    {
        public float lat { get; set; }
        public float lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Start_Location
    {
        public float lat { get; set; }
        public float lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Step
    {
        public Distance1 distance { get; set; }
        public Duration1 duration { get; set; }
        public End_Location1 end_location { get; set; }
        public string html_instructions { get; set; }
        public Polyline polyline { get; set; }
        public Start_Location1 start_location { get; set; }
        public string travel_mode { get; set; }
        public string maneuver { get; set; }
    }

    public class Distance1
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Duration1
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
    }

    public class End_Location1
    {
        public float lat { get; set; }
        public float lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Polyline
    {
        public string points { get; set; }
    }

    public class Start_Location1
    {
        public float lat { get; set; }
        public float lng { get; set; }
    }
```

Assim você vai ter o objeto JSON no seu código e através dele conseguir os itens que você deseja.

Comment: se isso funcionar, eu te devo minha vida

Comment: sim, te devo a vida hahah
Muito obrigada

Comment: kkkkkkk De nada